# Push-Based Events in a Services Oriented Architecture

Tags: java, soa, event-programming, message-queue

I have come to a point, in building a services oriented architecture (on top of Thrift), that I need to expose events and allow listeners.

My initial thought was, "create an EventService" to handle publishing and subscribing to events. That EventService can use whatever implementation it desires to actually distribute the events. My client automatically round-robins service requests to available service hosts which are determined using Zookeeper-based service discovery. So, I'd probably use JMS inside of EventService mainly for the purpose of persisting messages (in the event that a service host for EventService goes down before it can distribute the message to all of the available listeners).

When I started considering this, I began looking into the differences between Queues and Topics. Topics unfortunately won't work for me, because (at least for now), all listeners *must* receive the message (even if they were down at the time the event was pushed, or hadn't made a subscription yet because they haven't completed startup (during deployment, for example) - messages should be queued until the service is available).

However, I don't want EventService to be responsible for handling all of the events. I don't think it should have the code to react to events inside of it. Each of the services should do what it needs with a given event. This would indicate that each service would need a JMS connection, which questions the value of having EventService at all (as the services could individually publish and subscribe to JMS directly). However, it also couples all of the services to JMS (when I'd rather that there be a single service that's responsible for determining *how* to distribute events).

What I had thought was to publish an event to EventService, which pulls a configuration of listeners from some configuration source (database, flat file, irrelevant for now). It replicates the message and pushes each one back into a queue with information specific to that listener (so, if there are 3 listeners, 1 event would become 3 events in JMS). Then, another thread in EventService (which is replicated, running on multiple hots) would be pulling from the queue, attempting to make the service call to the "listener", and returning the message to the queue (if the service is down), or discarding the message (if the listener completed successfully).

**tl;dr**

If I have an EventService that is responsible for receiving events and delegating service calls to "event listeners," (which are really just endpoints on other services), how should it know how to craft the service call? Should I create a generic "Event" object that is shared among all services? Then, the EventService can just construct this object and pass it to the service call. Or is there a better answer to this problem entirely?

Comment: I think you have some good questions here, but maybe you could break them up into a few questions on this site? Or ask one particular one at a time and see where that leads you? This kind of sounds like you're asking for someone to give you an architecture rather than asking a question.. or if there's a question in there, I can't find it?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Sorry, I have updated the question to include what I'm really trying to ask at the end. But I am leaving the option on the table for someone to suggest that I'm going about this the wrong way entirely.

Comment: Don't worry about leaving options open, if an engineer thinks you're doing something wrong they don't usually keep their mouths shut, do they? :)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Fair point. We tend to be part of the "brutally honest" crowd. Something along the lines of: "your entire design sucks. Do it again."

Comment: You might think about this generic service just passing around the serialized forms of whatever messages it gets. Then it doesn't care about the type, it's up to publishers and subscribers to be sure they have a common language. Your delegator just passes what it's given. You may not need to even worry about serializer stuff, working in ActiveMQ with NMS there's built in message objects from the NMS framework, I presume JMS similarly has a general message object you can receive and forward.

Comment: Also I would strongly consider that you might be creating significantly greater complexity than is necessary just to work around a small edge case where simpler workarounds may be fine.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa That's entirely a possibility. Which part specifically are you referring to? EventService in its entirety? I'd really like to abstract JMS away from the individual services.

Comment: I just mean all the complexity of this delegator when JMS does event delegation for you with topics just fine, you want to write this other service just for the edge case that a subscriber doesn't come up before anything is published; That's really a deployment concern though and not one you should be making entire services to solve when you could simply ensure that the publishing service is turned on last. If you want code to be certain of this stuff, make a shared DB lists consumers so the publisher journals everything untill all consumers report in that they're up and subscribed

Comment: many different coordination efforts are greatly simpler than this delegator service which is really just another eventing service when you already have one (JMS)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa The issue is that *all* services are potentially publishers. Any service can produce events that other services may be interested in. So, there's no deploy order that can solve for this. So, alternatively, the event distributor can hold events in memory until all subscribers are active, before distributing - but my next question would be: who subscribes? If all service nodes subscribe, they all receive the same event, and all react individually. If one does, it takes all the load. I'd need a distributable way to do that. Maybe I don't fully understand JMS/ActiveMQ

Comment: Join [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) and we can discuss. It sounds like you might be fundamentally misunderstanding messaging based architectures or just missing a design for yours

Answer (score 1):

If the service must receive the message, even though it is unaware of its existence, then the publish/subscribe pattern is not the answer. Publishers are not supposed to know about their subscribers. The subscriber is supposed to care, not the publisher.

If the "publisher" is responsible for maintaining messages, then what you want is polling.

Comment: Thats why messaging middleware exists. Durable subscriptions makes sure that all publications gets through without polling.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this Event Service introduces some kind of orchestration. This service is tightly coupled with all the services it interacts with, resulting in a chatty communication, very likely implemented with synchronous request-reply, which is probably the biggest evil [of all](https://medium.com/@wrong.about/wrong-ways-of-defining-service-boundaries-d9e313007bcc).

Think of this service when it will orchestrate 100 services. It sounds pretty scary.

Besides that, the logic is inevitably spread over two services: the central governing service and invoked service because of a problem I’ve just mentioned -- synchronous communication nature between them.

After all, this looks like a smart pipes approach. Definitely not good.

[Here](http://nic.ferrier.me.uk/blog/2013_12/what-is-service-choreography) is a good and more detailed overview of this approach.

> Or is there a better answer to this problem entirely?

I think there is. Let all your services listen to events they are interested in.